# How to store form data in xml in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was wondering if there is any way to save form values in an xml format and reload it later.

I want to pass in my model (containing all form values) and save the form content in an xml file.

Many thanks

Sandra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do this by serializing my model to xml by using the DataContractSerializer and them save the MemoryStream